# W 8.1 Webview cookie

Tags: c#, xaml, cookies, webview, windows-8.1

I need to get a cookie from webview control (W 8.1, c#, xaml).

First I load the page inside the Webview like this:

```
<WebView x:Name="WebviewControl" FrameNavigationCompleted="Webview_FrameNavigationCompleted" /> 

WebviewControl.Navigate(new Uri("example.com"));
```

Then, the user log inside tha page and I need to get the cookie.

I try this:

```
private void Webview_FrameNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    HttpBaseProtocolFilter baseFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    foreach (HttpCookie cookie in baseFilter.CookieManager.GetCookies(new Uri(sender.Source.ToString()))
        {
            if (cookie.Name.Equals("cookieName"))
            {
                string value = cookie.Value;
            }
        }  
}
```

The problem is that the cookie dosen`t exist inside the cookiemanager.
I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the `Set-Cookie` header the server is sending back? Can you look at it using something like *Fiddler*?

Comment: Thanks, ill try to use fiddler!

Comment: I found that the cookie does not exist using Fiddler, so the problem is in the server and not in my code @kiewic, thanks.